# Repeat code with IF

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, radio-button, navbar

I have text on the button that changes when a radio button is clicked. But when I click the button twice the text doesn't appear anymore. And I want some cycle/repeat code for when I clicking the radiobuttons more than once the text on the button always appears. Some help?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar2 navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-bottom">
        <div id="navbarbackground" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar" id="nav-content">
                <label class="labl icon-package-flat">
                    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location='#formulario';" id="radioInfo" name="radioname" value="Submeter pedido de Informação geral" checked="checked" />
                    <div class="text"><center class="iconcenter"><i class="icon icon-info"></i></center>Informação geral</div>
                </label>
                <label class="labl icon-package-flat">
                    <a href="#formulario"></a>
                    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location='#formulario';" id="radioTestDrive" name="radioname" value="Submeter pedido de Test drive" />
                    <div class="text"><center class="iconcenter2"><i class="icon icon-test_drive"></i></center>Test drive</div>
                </label>
                <label class="labl icon-package-flat">
                    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location='#formulario';" id="radioFinancing" name="radioname" value="Submeter pedido de Financiamento" />
                    <div class="text"><center class="iconcenter2"><i class="icon icon-calculator"></i></center>Financiamento</div>
                </label>
                <label class="labl icon-package-flat">
                    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location='#formulario';" id="radioCatalog" name="radioname" value="Submeter pedido de Catálogo" />
                    <div class="text"><center class="iconcenter2"><i class="icon icon-printed"></i></center>Catálogo</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**HTML BUTTON**

```
<div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
<center> <section class="icon-package-flat"> <button  id="btnsubmeter" class="contact100-form-btn"><i class="icon icon-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span id="lblOpcao">Submeter pedido de informação geral</span></button>
</section></center> </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $("[name='radioname']").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.radio').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var val = $(this).attr('data-value');

            if ($(this).id == "radioInfo") {
                $("#lblOpcao").text("Submeter pedido de Informação geral");
            }

            if ($(this).id == "radioFinancing") {
                $("#lblOpcao").text("Submeter pedido de financiamento");
            }

            if ($(this).id == "radioTestDrive") {
                $("#lblOpcao").text("Submeter pedido de Test drive");
            }

            if ($(this).id == "radioCatalog") {
                $("#lblOpcao").text("Submeter pedido de Catálogo");
            }

            $("#lblOpcao").text($(this).val());
            //alert(val);
            $(this).parent().find('input').val(val);        
        });

        function toggle(button) { if (radio.value == "OFF") { radio.value = "ON"; } else { radio.value = "OFF"; } }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `value` from the `$(this).attr('data-value')`, which doesn't  return what you want. And then you set it again to the value. It is clearing the radiobutton value.

Also you don't need to specify it's text in the radiobutton value AND in the JS code. That's ambiguous and may cause problems on maintance.

---

## Bad Solution

You can make it work by just changing that line:

From:
`var val = $(this).attr('data-value');`
To:
`var val = $(this).val();`

---

## Suggested Solution

Try to replace your entire `.click()` event to:

```
    $("[name='radioname']").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.radio').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $("#lblOpcao").text($(this).val());  
    });
```

I removed some useless logic. You are checking the radiobutton id to set a specific text on the lblOpcao, but you aren't using it. You always override it with the `.val()` text. You are also setting the radiobutton value to the same value.

Comment: thank you so much for your attention. I was able to solve the problem with this solution :)

Comment: If that helped you, please mark it as [Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :D